# OO Javascript Game, how can i add players the game's player array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the beginning of a very simple object oriented javascript game. I am having trouble adding players to the Games players[] array. how can this be done?

i've removed all the code not relevant to the question

```
var BobsGame = function(){
this.Players = [];
}

BobsGame.prototype.addPlayer = function(Player){
//not working
Player.Game = this;
this.Players.push(Player);
Player.setId = function(this.Players.length) {
    return this.Players.length;
}
return this;
}

var Player = function(name){
this.Game = null;
this.score = 0;
this.name = name;
this.id = null;
//  return alert('Player ' + this.name + ' has been created');
}

var myGame = new BobsGame();

var Player1 = new Player("Tom");
var Player2 = new Player("Bob");

myGame.addPlayer(Player1);
```

Comment: use Array.prototyspe.push(); as you already do. WHat's the problem with yourt current code? The only problem is that you're naming a variable (`Player`) the same way you already named a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think you're trying:

```
var BobsGame = function () {
    this.Players = [];
};

BobsGame.prototype.addPlayer = function (Player) {
    this.Players.push(Player);
    Player.id = this.Players.length;
    return this;
};

var Player = function (name) {
    this.score = 0;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = null;
    //  return alert('Player ' + this.name + ' has been created');
};

var myGame = new BobsGame();

var Player1 = new Player("Tom");
var Player2 = new Player("Bob");

myGame.addPlayer(Player1);
```

The error was in the following code:

```
Player.setId = function(this.Players.length) {
    return this.Players.length;
}
```

Here you're trying creating a function called `setId`, but you can't define `this.Players.length` as an argument. So assuming you're trying to set the id of the player to the length of the players array, you can simple assign it like this:

```
Player.id = this.Players.length;
```

By the way, I do recommend you don't call the argument of `addPlayer` "`Player`" since this will hide the already defined function `Player`. You might want to rename it to "`player`".